# How do I append only the new indices to a table with an HDFS store

Tags: python, pandas, hdfs, pytables

I am going to be iterating through many data frames to append to a table in an hdfs store.  The indices will overlap with each other.  I want to append only the rows with indices that aren't already in the store.

---

## [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Consider my data frames `d1` and `d2`:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {('a', 'x'): {'col': 1}, ('a', 'y'): {'col': 1}}, orient='index')
d2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {('b', 'x'): {'col': 2}, ('a', 'y'): {'col': 2}}, orient='index')

print(d1, '\n\n', d2)

     col
a x    1
  y    1 

      col
a y    2
b x    2
```

I want to accomplish the same logic as the following:

```
d1.append(d2.loc[d2.index.difference(d1.index)])

     col
a x    1
  y    1
b x    2
```

But I want this for appending to the hdfs store.

## What I've Tried

```
d1.to_hdf('test.h5', 'mytable', format='table')
d2.to_hdf('test.h5', 'mytable', append=True)

pd.read_hdf('test.h5', 'mytable')

     col
a x    1
  y    1
  y    2
b x    2
```

You can see that the index `('a', 'y')` is duplicated with the two different values.  I'm assuming there is a way to check the index values in the table prior to appending new rows to the table.

Comment: [**@Jeff's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19326312/2336654) combined with Grr's answer got me where I needed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to initialize the store first. Then you should be able to assign a dataframe to `mytable` and work with it just like you did in your dataframe only example.

```
store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')

store['mytable'] = d1
store['mytable'].append(d2.loc[d2.index.difference(store['mytable'].index)])

     col
a x    1
  y    1
b x    2
```

Comment: This is more what I was looking for.  `store.append('mytable', d2.loc[d2.index.difference(store['mytable'].index)])`.  This solution is good.  However, it seems to require that I read the entire stored data frame into memory just to get at its index.  I'm going to leave the question open, for now, to see if I can get an answer where I can read just the index and not the entire data frame.  I might even be wrong about my interpretation of what's going on.  Open to further explanation... Hi btw!

Comment: Hey! And yea thats a good point. I'm pretty sure you can access single columns from HDFS, so maybe get just the index and then do the diff and append? Not really sure though.